# Heroku help Amazon RDS rails push database error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I get a 503 Error when trying to push my database to Amazon RDS

```
Home@PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
$ heroku db:push
Loaded Taps v0.3.19
Auto-detected local database: mysql://root@127.0.0.1/konkurranceportalen?encodin
g=utf8
Warning: Data in the app 'vinderhimlen' will be overwritten and will not be reco
verable.

 !    WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: vinderhimlen
 !    To proceed, type "vinderhimlen" or re-run this command with --confirm vind
erhimlen

> vinderhimlen
Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:01:07
Sending indexes
admins:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
slugs:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:02
Sending data
7 tables, 138 records
admins:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
kategoris:       0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201103182120.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 503
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or
g/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <style type="text/css">
        html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
      </style>
    <title>Application Error</title></head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
        <p>Application Error</p>
      </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>

Home@PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
$
```

My Heroku log http://pastie.org/1687466

Comment: Is there anything in `$ heroku logs`?

Comment: Yes http://pastie.org/1687466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were that Amazon RDS firewall did block Heroku.
In Amazon AWS > Amazon RDS I did go into the security group and did add a EC2 Security Group.

With following details:

```
Security Group: default
AWS Account ID: 098166147350
```