# Rails database.yml question when using Amazon RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How should my database.yml production look like when I am using Heroku and Amazon RDS?

My database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
# gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
# gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'

    development:
      adapter: mysql
      database: konkurranceportalen
      encoding: utf8
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password: 
      socket: C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqld.sock
      host: 127.0.0.1

    # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
    # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
    # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

    test:
      adapter: mysql
      database: rails_t
      encoding: utf8
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password: 
      socket: C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqld.sock
      host: 127.0.0.1

    production:
      adapter: mysql
      database: rails_t
      encoding: utf8
      pool: 5
      username: root
      password: 
      socket: C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqld.sock
      host: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the Heroku docs for details of the Amazon RDS addon - [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon_rds)

Comment: I have read the guide. But when I try to push my MySql database to Amazon RDS I get this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357486/heroku-help-amazon-rds-rails-push-database-error

Answer (score 0):

View my walkthrough for solving this issue here: [Heroku help deploying Rails app that uses Mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362288/heroku-help-deploying-rails-app-that-uses-mysql-database/5853261#5853261)