# Getting an 'Application Error' when trying to push my database to Amazon RDS with the heroku gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-rds, taps

Whenever I try to push my local mysql database to Amazon RDS I get a 503 application error:

```
bundle exec heroku db:push
...
Sending schema
Schema:         40% |================                          | ETA:  00:00:38
Saving session to push_201106170529.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 503
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <style type="text/css">
     html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
     iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
    </style>
    <title>Application Error</title></head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <iframe src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
    <p>Application Error</p>
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm using taps 0.3.23

While the error message is similar to the one reported here : [Heroku help Amazon RDS rails push database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357486/heroku-help-amazon-rds-rails-push-database-error) my problem is not related to Amazon's security group as this is already configured.

Anybody else encountering this issue?

Comment: It seems to have been fixed. Pushing works again.

In the meantime I did it manually, if somebody should run in the same problem:
`mysqldump -u root <development_database> | mysql -u <username> -p<secretpassword> --host <rds_url> -C <rds_databasename>`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same HTML response message and HTTP error code using Heroku with a CURL POST request.

Executing `heroku logs | tail` gave me more insights:

```
2016-04-20T10:56:17.509354+00:00 heroku[router]: 
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST [...]
```

The H12 error denotes a request timeout. That means an "HTTP request took longer than 30 seconds to complete" [1].

More on request timeouts on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout.

[1] https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout

Answer (score 0):

I had the same response with heroku db:push, the first time I attempted.

However, when I ran it a second time, there was no error, and the db pushed.

Comment: It wasn't the first time I ran this command, but it suddenly stopped working, I tried several times and from several computers without success. It's only a week later that things seemed to be back to normal.

Comment: I agree. This seems to be an intermittent problem. Last night it was working reliably, and today it fails every time, but in different parts of the process.