# Heroku DB:push is not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm fairly new to Heroku and deploying Rails app. I have an app hosted in Heroku with a MySQL database, been working flawlessly for a month or so. Today, I did a db:pull and took longer than expected. When I did db:push, I'm getting an error:

```
Sending schema>
Schema:         17% |=======                                   | ETA:  00:00:22
Saving session to push_201107211055.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 503
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
    iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
  </style>
<title>Application Error</title></head>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
    <p>Application Error</p>
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357486/heroku-help-amazon-rds-rails-push-database-error

Comment: I went into that question, but the answer seems not to apply to my case. I don't have an Amazon AWS > Amazon RDS log in or account.

Comment: can you explicitly show which gems you are using to map databases on local and production environments.

Comment: Now it went back to working as expected. Thanks everyone for the support.

Comment: I take it you've retried and get the same message?

Comment: Can you please let us know the solution? I have a similar problem but with error code 503.

Answer (score 2):

(while this may not "fix" anything, it did work for me twice, definitely worth a shot) try:

```
heroku restart
heroku db:push --confirm app-name-1234
```

Comment: 'heroku restart' fixed a problem I've been having with db:pull

Answer (score 0):

do you have the taps gem?

`gem install taps`

[Source](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps)

Comment: Yes, I do have the taps gem installed, this been working for the past month.